# How to automate an API which takes different combinations of query params and gives corresponding result (Using Karate)

Tags: karate

I have a versatile get API which takes multiple query params and gives a corresponding response for each combination of query params. The set of combinations is defined. I need to automate the API so that each case is covered and the response is verified using Karate. I wish to use minimum number of feature files. Please suggest a way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really read the docs and look at the [demos](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo) and save yourself a lot of time.

Note that you can use the [`params`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#keywords-that-set-multiple-key-value-pairs-in-one-step) keyword for this use-case, and `null` values will be ignored (no query param will be set).

```
Scenario Outline:
    * def query = { name: <name>, country: <country>, active: <active>, limit: <limit> }

    Given path 'search'
    And params query
    When method get
    Then status 200
    # response should NOT contain a key expected to be missing
    And match response !contains <missing>

    # observe how strings are enclosed in quotes, and we set null-s here below
    # and you can get creative by stuffing json into table cells !
    Examples:
    | name   | country   | active | limit | missing                                                      |
    | 'foo'  | 'IN'      | true   |     1 | {}                                                           |
    | 'bar'  | null      | null   |     5 | { country: '#notnull', active: '#notnull' }                  |
    | 'baz'  | 'JP'      | null   |  null | { active: '#notnull', limit: '#notnull' }                    |
    | null   | 'US'      | null   |     3 | { name: '#notnull', active: '#notnull' }                     |
    | null   | null      | false  |  null | { name: '#notnull', country: '#notnull', limit: '#notnull' } |
```