# Specific query params in Karate

Tags: parameters, request, karate

My API path looks like https://bps.com/blogins??query=(blID==<value_obtained_from_prev_request>)

<value_obtained_from_prev_request> - This is a long integer value which is obtained from response payload of previous request in the same scenario. I am storing this value in a variable using

- def Myid = response.id

How are we supposed to give the query param for these kind of requests in Karate?

Comment: please read the documentation also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50659434/143475